Cannot delete a temp file after spring boot update with 3.1.2 version in windows Server
We are currently facing issues in a Spring Boot application with file upload with multipart in Windows Server, less than 2022 version. The problems are like java.io.unchecked exception :Error : cannot delete temp file c://user/AppData/local/temp/tomcat.port.uuid/root/xxx.tmp . The recent changes we have done was udating Spring Boot to 3.1.2 updating the JDK17 version. Since then, we were encountering the errors. Can anyone suggest on this?
In Windows 10 and latest Windows Server 2022 we have tried the same, but didn't face the issue there.
We got the below error from the Spring Boot application after doing a file upload.
ERROR 07.04.24 06:49:59,284 [https-jsse-nio-8585-exec-3] Http11Processor           Error processing request
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8585.7214288071310798307\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_80353576_cb85_40bc_938c_3088b7428c44_00142374.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:429) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:53) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:446) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:419) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[test.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[test.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8585.7214288071310798307\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_80353576_cb85_40bc_938c_3088b7428c44_00142374.tmp
    ... 13 more


Please edit your question to add full stack trace of the error as well as relevant part of the code that is doing the deletion.

@JorgeCampos Hi , I have updated trace which we got in log

I would suggest a few things: checking the user that is running your application, whether it has permission to modify that folder; that folder doesn't look like an actual OS temp folder, rather a manually set one, so try using the OS temp folder instead (unless the user you are using is test); make sure that any streams (input or output) associated with the file are being properly closed (that's why I asked for the code by the way); check if the version of Tomcat you are using with Spring Boot 3.1.2 is fully compatible with JDK 17; enable debugging on the for spring boot logs

@JorgeCampos I have modified the user name as test in the place of user account, For windows 10 we have permission for the folder but for windows server we have changed the Temp folder from the above path to some other path which has permission by using -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\test\temp, even though we got the above error in windows server.

@JorgeCampos we have ensured all the streams are closed  and I have checked the tomcat version with Spring boot is 10.1.11 which embedded with this spring boot version 3.1.2 is compatible

Do you have the configuration to specify the temp folder for multipart files? spring.servlet.multipart.location See it on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html

@JorgeCampos we are not setting any temp location  property in application.properties file,but we have tried with  -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\test\temp and changed the temp location even though we got the error as above

Please read the documentation I just shared and what is it for. Meaning you are probably missing it.

@JorgeCampos  We are not having this configuration in application-properties.xml "spring.servlet.multipart.location"

We will add this configuration in application.properties file and update here

@JorgeCampos, I have added the configuration to specify the multipart location by setting the path to spring.servlet.multipart.location property. Even though we got the same error with "ERROR 18.06.24 15:00:09,910 [http-nio-8585-exec-1] Http11Processor           Error processing request
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\user\test\temp\upload_5db5cc58_8ed6_4f69_9404_eeaed6c54e5b_00000004.tmp" , I am able to see the temporary files in the path which I have given in the " spring.servlet.multipart.location" property.
